# How to use legacy_seq2seq for TensorFlow 2?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, seq2seq

I am new to TensorFlow and I am wanting to use tensorflow.config.legacy_seq2se, specifically [embedding_rnn_seq2seq()](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7Epython/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_seq2seq) and I can't figure out how to use it (or if there is an equivalent method) for TensorFlow 2.

I know that in TensorFlow 2, TensorFlow removed contrib and according to [this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ/edit#gid=0)
tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq has been deleted and replaced with tf.seq2seq in TensorFlow 2, but I can't find embedding_rnn_seq2seq() in the [tf.seq2seq documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq) I have seen.

The reason I want to use it is I am trying to implement something similar to what is done with embedding_rnn_seq2seq() in this [article](https://adeshpande3.github.io/How-I-Used-Deep-Learning-to-Train-a-Chatbot-to-Talk-Like-Me). So is there an equivalent in tensorflow 2, or is there a different way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

According to [https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow~python/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_seq2seq](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7Epython/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_seq2seq) , contrib.legacy_rnn_seq2seq createsan embedding of an argument that you pass, encoder_inputs (the shape is num_encoder_symbols x input_size). It then runs an RNN to encode the embedded encoder_inputs to convert it into a state vector. Then it embeds another argument you pass decoder_inputs (the shape is num_decoder_symbols x input_size). Next it runs an RNN decoder initialized with with the last encoder state, on the embedded decoder_inputs.

Contrib was a community maintained part of Tensorflow, and seq2seq was part of it. In Tensorflow 2 it was removed.
You could just use a Tensorflow_addons which contains community made add ons including seq2seq I believe.

You can import Tensorflow add ons via

```
import tensorflow_addons
```

Or you could just use a Tensorflow version that still has Seq2Seq (I believe 1.1 is the latest).

There are also things like bi-directional recurrent neural networks and dynamic RNNs (they are basically a new version of seq2seq) that may work.